# Basic changes to Hello World GRPC

Tags: linux, go, tcp, grpc, grpc-go

I am using `gRPC` with `Golang`.

After successfully running their `HelloWorld tutorial` which required me to add a second function, compile the protoc file, I decided to make some further changes.

My code is included, which appears not to work because it expects the `pb` variable to be a HelloWorld object, or something, as shown in the error message in **command line** below. Could someone please tell me where I have gone wrong, for what should be some very small changes.

I have fixed some typos in my original post's code below.

**Command line:**

```
go run server/server.go
# command-line-arguments
server/server.go:24:71: undefined: helloworld.TheGRPCNotificationMessage
```

**Command line protoc file:**

> protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=.
> --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative GRPCNotification/GRPCNotification.proto

**GRPCNotification.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

option go_package = "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "io.grpc.examples.helloworld";
option java_outer_classname = "HelloWorldProto";

package grpcnotificationpackage;

// The greeting service definition.
service TheGRPCNotificationService {
  // Sends a notification and nothing sent back
  rpc SendNotificationWithGRPC (TheGRPCNotificationMessage) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);
  // Receives a notification and does not reply
  rpc ReceiveNotificationWithGRPC (stream TheGRPCNotificationMessage) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);
}

// The request notification message
message TheGRPCNotificationMessage {
  string message = 1;
  // ... add more here
}

// Since nothing gets returned from server we need this empty
message Empty {
  // Nothing goes here
}
```

**Client.go**

```
// Package main implements a client for Greeter service.
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    pb "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld"
)

const (
    address     = "localhost:50051"
    defaultName = "world"
)

func main() {
    // Set up a connection to the server.
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(address, grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("did not connect: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    c := pb.NewGreeterClient(conn)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    r, err := c.SendNotificationWithGRPC(ctx, &pb.TheGRPCNotificationMessage{Message: "Horse"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not greet: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Sent a message, please check it reached server...")
}
```

**Server.go**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    pb "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld"
)

const (
    port = ":50051"
)


// server is used to implement helloworld.GreeterServer
type server struct {
    pb.UnimplementedGreeterServer
}


// SendNotificationWithGRPC implements helloworld.GreeterServer   <--- Problem?
func (s *server) ReceiveNotificationWithGRPC(ctx context.Context, in *pb.TheGRPCNotificationMessage) {
    log.Printf("Received: %v", in.Name)
}

func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterGreeterServer(s, &server{})
    log.Printf("server listening at %v", lis.Addr())
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}
```

I wish the example tutorial did not glue me to it so roughly!

Answer (score 2):

Your `go_package` and `client.go` and `server.go` package imports are incorrect. This is a "fiddly" part of gRPC but it results because the protocol must support many (varied) languages and their package solutions.

You've also renamed the service and methods so can't use e.g. `GreeterService` as this no longer exists. Most editors (e.g. VSCode) will help you navigate packages to find naming errors.

```golang
pb "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld"
```

1. Assuming your code is in a Go Module called `${REPO}` (and probably something of the form `github.com/YOUR-ORG/YOUR-REPO`, i.e. you:

```sh
go mod init ${REPO}
```

2. In the proto file, for Golang (I'll leave the other languages for you to solve), you'll want:

```
option go_package = "${REPO}/helloworld";
```

> **NOTE** Replace `${REPO}` with its value i.e. `github.com/....`

3. I would encourage you to be consistent with proto package name name `grpcnotificationpackage` and your generated code package names but, for now, your proto package is `grpcnotificationpackage` but you're generating code into `helloworld`.
4. Create a directory in the repo called `helloworld`. You're asking `protoc` to generate Go source (`go_package`) into a package called `${REPO}/helloworld` and Go requires that the files be in a directory called `helloworld` in your repo.
5. Then:

```sh
protoc \
--go_out=${PWD}/helloworld \
--go_opt=paths=source_relative \
--go-grpc_out=${PWD}/helloworld \
--go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
GRPCNotification.proto
```

There are various flavors of this command but this will generate the sources into `${PWD}/helloworld` in your repo.

6. Then you must import correctly:

```
import (
  ...
  ${REPO}/helloworld
)
```

7. Then you must correct your references. If you call a service `TheGRPCNotificationService` and a method `SendNotificationWithGRPC` and a message `TheGRPCNotificationMessage`, this is what protoc will generate (you can review the generated Go sources to confirm this). So:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"

    pb "${REPO}/helloworld"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
)

const (
    port = ":50051"
)

// Ensure that `server` implements the interface
var _ pb.TheGRPCNotificationServiceServer = &server{}

// server is used to implement helloworld.GreeterServer
type server struct {
    pb.UnimplementedTheGRPCNotificationServiceServer
}

// This is the correct signature of the method
func (s *server) ReceiveNotificationWithGRPC(
    stream pb.TheGRPCNotificationService_ReceiveNotificationWithGRPCServer,
) error {
    // Implement
    return status.Errorf(codes.Unimplemented, "not implemented")
}

func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterTheGRPCNotificationServiceServer(s, &server{})
    log.Printf("server listening at %v", lis.Addr())
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}
```

8. I don't recommend `returns (google.protobuf.Empty)`. I don't know whether there's a best practice for this but I think it's better to return a message that contains no fields, e.g.:

```proto
rpc Foo (FooRequest) returns (FooResponse);

message FooResponse {}
```

9. Consider using a tool such as [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) to debug:

In this example, `gRPCurl` uses the proto not the service to enumerate the services (defined in the proto):

```sh
grpcurl \
-plaintext \
--proto *.proto \
localhost:50051 list
```

Yields:

```
grpcnotificationpackage.TheGRPCNotificationService
```

Same-same but for the methods for the given service:

```
grpcurl \
-plaintext \
--proto *.proto \
localhost:50051 list grpcnotificationpackage.TheGRPCNotificationService
```

Yields the methods:

```
grpcnotificationpackage.TheGRPCNotificationService.ReceiveNotificationWithGRPC
grpcnotificationpackage.TheGRPCNotificationService.SendNotificationWithGRPC
```

Invoke the server streaming method:

```
grpcurl \
-plaintext \
--proto *.proto \
localhost:50051 grpcnotificationpackage.TheGRPCNotificationService.ReceiveNotificationWithGRPC
```

Yields (correctly an Unimplemented error)

```
ERROR:
  Code: Unimplemented
  Message: not implemented
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. Would you mind providing me with a client source code, as at the moment above there is just code for the server.

Comment: I need a client source code so I can send messages to the server.